# apportable project compiling error

Tags: debugging, build, apportable

I got this compiling error from my xcode 4.6.2 projects.  I tested on two of them, and it always stop in the same place.  I don't recognize any of those error in both of my code.  What should I do?

I did apportable build on both projects.   Here are the logs.  Is there anything more useful that help me identify the error?

jinfe apple$ apportable build

```
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Loading configuration.
Finished parsing configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 739, in <module>
    run(env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 705, in run
    results = actions[args.action](env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 77, in BuildAction
    site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET'])
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 359, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 628, in App
    results = env.BuildApp(sources=sources, header_paths=headers, defines=defines, flags=flags, config=configs, deps=deps, libs=libs, java_libs=java_libs, assets=assets, pch=pchs, modules=modules, java_sources=java_sources, java_sourcepaths=java_sourcepaths, java_res_dirs=java_res_dirs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/lib/scons/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 223, in __call__
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 997, in BuildApp
    lib = BuildLibrary(env, env['XCODEBUILD_TARGET'], sources=sources, header_paths=header_paths, static=True, defines=defines, flags=flags, deps=deps, libs=libs, pch=pch, app=True, java_libs=java_libs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 632, in BuildLibrary
    build.headermap.dump(f, path['hmap'])
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/headermap.py", line 194, in dump
    string_table.write(s + '\0')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

-- Here's the 2nd log

```
CityWar apple$ apportable build
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Loading configuration.
Finished parsing configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 739, in <module>
    run(env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 705, in run
    results = actions[args.action](env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 77, in BuildAction
    site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET'])
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 359, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 628, in App
    results = env.BuildApp(sources=sources, header_paths=headers, defines=defines, flags=flags, config=configs, deps=deps, libs=libs, java_libs=java_libs, assets=assets, pch=pchs, modules=modules, java_sources=java_sources, java_sourcepaths=java_sourcepaths, java_res_dirs=java_res_dirs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/lib/scons/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 223, in __call__
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 997, in BuildApp
    lib = BuildLibrary(env, env['XCODEBUILD_TARGET'], sources=sources, header_paths=header_paths, static=True, defines=defines, flags=flags, deps=deps, libs=libs, pch=pch, app=True, java_libs=java_libs)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 632, in BuildLibrary
    build.headermap.dump(f, path['hmap'])
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/headermap.py", line 194, in dump
    string_table.write(s + '\0')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 33-36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Can you share your experience ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a non-ASCII character in a header file. To analyze, add logging to $HOME/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/headermap.py like :

```
     for s in string_tbl:
+        print 'header is ' + s
         string_pos[s] = string_table.tell()
         string_table.write(s + '\0')
```